# Rails: Respond with js to Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, respond-to

I encountered some weird behaviour when using an ajax request to get a response from a rails controller action.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/notifications',
    success: function(result) {
        eval(result);
    }
});
```

```ruby
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Page not accessible' }
        format.js
    end
end
```

So this respond_to block works fine when using requests with rails' `remote: true` option, but with the ajax call it just redirects the request to `root_url`.

When specifying `json` as `dataType` of the Ajax request. The so returns the JavaScript just fine, but because it is not valid `json`, `eval()` does not run it.

Is there a way too either start a rails remote request from within JavaScript or specify a data type with which the returned JavaScript is executable?

---

Even specifying `dataType: 'text/javascript',` in the ajax call does not do the trick.

Comment: Try `dataType: 'script'`

Comment: @jonhue
Did you try to check `if request.xhr?` in your index-action?

Comment: @pavan Thanks for your suggestion! I'll try it when I get home later

Comment: @cnnr No, why would I do that? `respond_to` should take care of that.

Answer (score 5):

> So this respond_to block works fine when using requests with rails'
>   remote: true option, but with the ajax call it just redirects the
>   request to root_url

So the request format that is coming to the controller is `HTML` not `JS`. Using `dataType: 'script'` generates the request as `JS` and should fix your problem.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'script',
  url: '/notifications'
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. It seems like it works - the ajax request returns the requested javascript. But at the same time the success callback does not execute it.

Comment: @jonhue What do you have in success callback?

Comment: I added it to the original post.

Comment: @jonhue Can you try response instead of result?